# UITableViewCell prototype reuse between two UITableViews in the same view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

Is it safe to deque UITableViewCell prototype from one table and use them in another?

When I want to display the UITableViewCell in the other UITableView I am simply dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier a reusable cell from the table where the prototype type cells are specified.  That is, not the UITableView they will be displayed in.

It seems to work fine and I haven't noticed any errors in the logs but I am concerned it might cause weird issues as I have not seen it done before.

Should I simply implement this using a separate nib for each cell?  Or is this approach fine, bad practice or dangerous?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (self.prototypesTableView == tableView) {
        cell = [self.prototypesTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType];
    }
    else if (self.otherTableView == tableView) {
        cell = [self.otherTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType] ?: [self.prototypesTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellType];
    }
}
```

Comment: In writing this I am now wondering what happens to the cells used in the other table I am guessing they just build up and are never reused.  Perhaps I have answered my own question.  I could always dequeu from correct table first and only go to the prototype table when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is now running in production and I have seen no ill affects caused by dequeueing reusable cells from one table and using them in another.  To ensure correct reuse I always dequeue from the "otherTableView" and if no UITableCell is available dequeue from the "prototypesTableView".

Although I implemented it like this for the sake expediency I would suggest it is better practice to implement it in the manner suggested by Michael, as it provides greater ability to share cells between view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain that each table view in memory has it's own queue of table view cells.

And when the table view (and view that hosts it) disappears, all the objects associated with it are released (assuming ARC here).  Having one view with two tables shouldn't matter:  each table has their own collection of cells to dequeue.

And in my own code, I frequently reuse the same custom "`UITableViewCell`" from one table to the next.  To register a custom UITableView cell (which would be the only object in a XIB file), I do:

```
UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName: @"SomeVeryCustomCell" bundle: nil];
if(nib)
{
    [myTableView registerNib: nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SomeVeryCustomCell"];
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I am looking for some sort of confirmation that it is okay to take a prototype cell created in one table and use it in another table.  This means in interface builder I only need to specify the prototypes in one table instead of two.  I don't think this is standard practice so I wanted to know if it can cause issues.
If I understand, you seem to be talking about using the external nib approach where the cell is specified in another nib file, I know you can do this but I already have the prototype cells specified in the storyboard and prefer not to migrate them to separate nibs.

Comment: +1 Because although it doesn't answer my question on safety, I think it is a better approach to cell reuse.